# AS3: Score based on timer

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer

I'm making a game in AS3 and I've been trying to make a score based on the time since the game started, the score would show when the game is over and would  basically be the seconds since the game started multiply by 1000. But I'm struggling to see how to do such thing since I've made the timer in a separate class and I'm trying to add the score to the main document class.

Here's what I've tried:

in the main class:

```
score.affichageScore.text = "votre score: " + chrono.seconds * 1000;
```

in this, is the timer class where I used a Date class:

```
package cem {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;


    public class Chronometre extends MovieClip {

        var begin: Date;
        public var seconds: uint = 0;

        public function Chronometre() {
            // constructor code



        }

        //************************************************Start the chrono*********************************************//
        public function start() {
            begin= new Date();
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _actualize);

        }

        //************************************************Stop the chrono*********************************************//
        public function stop() {

            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _actualize);

        }

        //************************************************Actualize the chrono*********************************************//
        private function _actualize(e: Event) {
            var msSpent: uint = new Date().getTime() - begin.getTime();



            seconds = Math.floor(msSpent/ 1000);
            var milliseconds: uint = msSpent- (seconds * 1000);

            affichage.text = seconds + ":" + milliseconds;

        }


    }

}
```

The obvious problem is how to get the ''seconds'' variable value from the timer class to the ''score'' variable in the main class?

Comment: Btw, there's a `Timer` class.

Comment: If it's a public variable it should be available to the main document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't create a new date on each frame - this is the worst option performance wise. As null have mentioned there is a timer class that could count the time but it can be even easier:

```
getTimer();
```

This returns the number of milliseconds since the swf was started. So you could do this straight in your main game class:

```
// when the game starts
gameStartTime = getTimer();

// when the game ends
gameEndTime = getTimer();

// calculate score with one point for each millisecond 
// (might be even better so that your scores won't always end in 000)
myScore = gameEndTime - gameStartTime;

// 1000 points for each second:
seconds = Math.floor((gameEndTime - gameStartTime) / 1000);
myScore = seconds * 1000;
```

Comment: I'm perhaps wrong, but if the player restart the game, this will be useless.
The method getTimer(); as you said returns the number of milliseconds since the swf was started.
If the player replay the game, there will be a problem with the getTimer() value.
Am I wrong?

Comment: @tatactic it looks like you're right. Might work for his particular use, but this could be a problem.

Comment: Well, if you set the gameStartTime at the start of each game then it will work just the same way - no matter if the gameStartTime will be 10 or 10.000.000